# How to extract values from a XML column in SQL and insert into new columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a column which is a XML column. I can use this to get some values from the xml:

```
Select TOP 10 
    mq.Id
    , m.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)') as VisitId
    , n.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)') as VisitorId
    , p.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)') as SearchId
from [Message] as mq
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/VisitId') as m(c)
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/VisitorId') as n(c)
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/SearchId') as p(c)
```

The xml is similar to:

```
<ActivityLoggingData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VisitId>c751de63-1305-4a5a-903e-677b5923d2c2</VisitId>
  <VisitorId>750b76eb-4727-4eb1-9737-cc7ce206e56b</VisitorId>
  <SearchId>baef33dc-8827-42a5-b2bd-a60ffe71aea8</SearchId>
  ...
</ActivityLoggingData>
```

Now, I added columns in table [Message]: VisitId, VisitorId and SearchId.

My question is: how can I extract these values from the xml column AND insert into these new columns? table Message has an Id column, we can use it and insert these values into temp table first, then update the [Message]. But, is there a way to do it without using temp table?

The database is SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for this? update mq set VisitId = m.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)'),
    VisitorId = n.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)'),
    SearchId =p.c.value('.', 'varchar(64)')
from [Message] as mq
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/VisitId') as m(c)
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/VisitorId') as n(c)
    outer apply mq.ActivityLoggingData.nodes('ActivityLoggingData/SearchId') as p(c);

Answer (score 2):

Please check this out.

```
DECLARE @xmldata XML = N'<ActivityLoggingData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VisitId>c751de63-1305-4a5a-903e-677b5923d2c2</VisitId>
  <VisitorId>750b76eb-4727-4eb1-9737-cc7ce206e56b</VisitorId>
  <SearchId>baef33dc-8827-42a5-b2bd-a60ffe71aea8</SearchId>
</ActivityLoggingData>'

DECLARE @T TABLE(VisitId nvarchar(50), VisitorId nvarchar(50), SearchId nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @T(VisitId, VisitorId, SearchId)
SELECT x.value(N'(VisitId)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)'),
       x.value(N'(VisitorId)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)'),
       x.value(N'(SearchId)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')
  FROM @xmldata.nodes(N'/ActivityLoggingData') AS XTbl(x)

SELECT * 
  FROM @T
```

Comment: Since those really are GUIDs, one could also use the T-SQL datatype `uniqueidentifier` (instead of `nvarchar(50)`). But your solution definitely works just fine

Comment: is there a way to just use ONE UPDATE to update the original table instead of using temp table/table variables to save the extracted value?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Could you please elaborate with an example.